# force to validate a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script below allow to validate all checkox inside a form.
My problem, I need to have just one to validate.
What is the element to change to verify if just one chabox is validated ?

```
<?php
                  $display_option .= '<div class="form-group ProductsInfoOptionCheckbox" options>';
                  $display_option .= '<label class="control-label ProductsInfoOptionCheckbox" for="input-option' . $option['products_option_id'] . '">' .  $option['name'] . '</label>';

                  foreach ($option['products_option_value'] as $t => $option_value) {
                    $display_option .= '<div class="checkbox">';
                    $display_option .= '<ul class="list-unstyled ProductsInfoOptionCheckbox">';
                    $display_option .= '<li class="ProductsInfoOptionCheckbox">';

                    $display_option .= HTML::checkboxField('id[' . $option['products_option_id'] . ']', $option_value['products_option_value_id'], $checked_attribute, 'required'); 
                 }
$display_option .= '<div>';
echo  $display_option;
?>

<script>                    
$(function(){
    var requiredCheckboxes = $('.options :checkbox[required]');
    requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
        if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
            requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
        } else {
            requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using:

```
$display_option .= '<div class="form-group ProductsInfoOptionCheckbox options">';
```